# Showing there are Infinitely Many Pairs that Satisfy Certain Criteria...

Tags: proof-explanation, infinity

I don't quite understand how to complete the following proof. Something tells me the solution is actually quite obvious, but for whatever reason I just can't crack it. Any help would be appreciated!

- In this problem, we discuss pairs of *consecutive* whole numbers satisfying the property that one of the numbers is a perfect square, and the other is a double of a perfect square.
- The task: Show that there are infinitely many pairs of the form $$(2a^2,b^2)$$ where the smaller number is the double of a perfect square satisfying the given property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the problem slightly. When I read it, it tells me that there are consecutive numbers, $x,y$ such that one of them is a perfect square, such that $\sqrt{y} = a$, and the other happens to have the property $x = 2b$, and $\sqrt{b} = c$ where a b and c are also integers.
Using this I believe that $(8,9)$ are one of the pairs you are looking for. 9 is a perfect square and $8 = 2\cdot4$ and 4 is a perfect square.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. (8,9) does fit the qualifications, then, as does (0,1) if you consider $$2*0^2$$ a valid expression. I'm still not sure how to prove that there infinitely many pairs that fit the criteria though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is equivalently phrased as follows:

> Prove that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation $$b^2 - 2a^2 = 1,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

Then, consider that if you can find one such solution, how can you generate an additional solution from it?  Can you devise a formula that says if $a = a_0$ and $b = b_0$, then you can find another solution $a = a_1$, $b = b_1$ from $a_0$ and $b_0$ such that $a_1$ and $b_1$ are also positive integers?

Answer (score 0):

If a pair $(a,b)$ satisfies the equation $2a^2+1 = b^2$, then the pair $(2ab,4a^2+1)$ does as well (check it!). And you already know of 1 such pair: (2,3). So, there are infinitely many.